# Alexa - enabling private skill for a team in alexa for business

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-for-business

I am an IAM user in my company's AWS account. I enabled Alexa for business and I created a private skill by creating an account in alexa for business and since I will be using Lambda and S3, I had to create the skill from Alexa developer console rather than with Alexa for business since Alexa for business offers only question and answer kind templates (Please correct me if I am wrong). After developing the skill, I submitted it for certification, but it failed, I don't want to certify and publish skill for alexa user base right now, but I want to enable it for my team in alexa for business. I am not finding the private skill developed in alexa developer console in my private skills under AWS management console's Alexa for business console. Any help in clarifying how to enable private skills for whole team is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link provides the procedure to enable a private skill in an Alexa for business account :https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-business/create-and-publish-private-skills-devconsole.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ChuckLaPress, However, it seems that this facility is available on in the United States for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer console to create and publish private skills. A private skill is published live, but is not available in the Alexa skill store. One prerequisites is to have Alexa for Business account which is only available in United States.

Another options adding users to your developer console, if you don’t want to give credentials to your developer console, I would recommend using beta test. The skill beta testing tool is only applicable for Alexa skill development, and you can send up to 500 invitations.
More information:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/skills-beta-testing-for-alexa-skills.html